# JUnit Test not rollbacking with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, mysql, junit

To put things in perspective, everything was working fine untill I had to format my working station. After I've managed to get the project running I ran the JUnit tests and most of my tests broke. The problem was because the database is not rolling back. Maybe I missed on some configuration, maybe on mysql it self.

So, these are my configuration/source files:

A JUnit Class declaration:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:testApplicationContext.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class ClientServiceTest {
```

The applicationContext for test scope:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what engine you use for application tables. MyISAM does not support transactions. You should use InnoDB.

To check engine, use query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
```